# Nodejs - Call a service from a typescript controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In my controller I have this method that renders a marko file sending an object to the view with data (dataView)

```
export const renderRecoveryData = (
  req: Request | any,
  reply: ResponseToolkit,
  callback: any
): void => {
  const dataView: { [key: string]: any } = {
    id: 1,
    info: getInfo(req, reply, callback),
  };
  templateEngine.renderFromTemplate(
    "./views/private/info/info.marko",
    dataView,
    req,
    reply,
  );
};
```

In the "info" property I want to load an object that obtains the data from the call to two services, using this method:

```
const getInfo = (req: Request | any, reply: any, callback: any): void => {
  const headers = helpers.setHeaders(req);
  const idNumber = req.yar.get('idNumber');
  async.parallel({
    personalData: (callback: any) => infoService.personalInfo(idNumber, headers, callback),
    addionalInfo: (callback: any) => infoService.addicionalInfo(headers, callback),
  }, (err: any, responses: any) => {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    console.log("response", responses);
    return responses;
  });
};
```

The console.log correctly shows me the object that I want to save in the "info" property of "dataView", but when I check what the view gets, the "info" property doesn't show up, it just shows me the "id" property

I call "renderRecoveryData" from a routes file:

```
  server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/{locale}/private/info/dashboard/step1",
    handler: renderRecoveryData,
  });
```

What can be the problem? Thanks

Comment: This is happening because `getInfo` is async function and you will have to either use `await` when calling it or render template in callback of `getInfo`. Other problem is you are not invoking callback in case of success (please replace`return responses` with `return callback(null, responses)`).

Comment: I am testing your recommendation, thank you

Comment: I added answer with detailed code changes. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues in the code:

1. `getInfo` is async function and there is no callback / await added when invoking it in controller.
2. Callback is not invoked on success in `getInfo` function.

Changing code to something like below should work:

```
export const renderRecoveryData = (
  req: Request | any,
  reply: ResponseToolkit,
  callback: any
): void => {

  getInfo(req, reply, (err, info) => {
    if(err) {
      // Handle error
    }

    const dataView: { [key: string]: any } = {
      id: 1,
      info,
    };
   
    templateEngine.renderFromTemplate(
      "./views/private/info/info.marko",
      dataView,
      req,
      reply,
    );
  });
  
};
```

```
const getInfo = (req: Request | any, reply: any, callback: any): void => {
  const headers = helpers.setHeaders(req);
  const idNumber = req.yar.get('idNumber');
  async.parallel({
    personalData: (callback: any) => infoService.personalInfo(idNumber, headers, callback),
    addionalInfo: (callback: any) => infoService.addicionalInfo(headers, callback),
  }, (err: any, responses: any) => {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    console.log("response", responses);
    return callback(err, responses);
  });
};
```

Comment: The solution works perfect, thank you very much (I just had to add "=>" in the "getInfo" function)

Comment: Yes missed it, edited answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the way you are returning response, I think you should pass the response to the callback

```
const getInfo = (req: Request | any, reply: any, callback: any): void => {
  const headers = helpers.setHeaders(req);
  const idNumber = req.yar.get("idNumber");
  async.parallel(
    {
      personalData: (callback: any) =>
        infoService.personalInfo(idNumber, headers, callback),
      addionalInfo: (callback: any) =>
        infoService.addicionalInfo(headers, callback),
    },
    callback // this is better
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes, the problem I also think is how I return it, I tried the callback, but nothing, the info property does not appear with the object and it does not give any error, thanks

Comment: from where renderRecoveryData function is called.

Comment: It is called from a typescript routes file, I update the question